# Strange behaviour of Angular's $watch

Tags: angularjs

Today I encounter some really strange behaviour in AngularJS using $watch. I simplified my code to the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/yLeLuard/

This example contains a service which will keep track of a `state` variable. The directives are used to bind a click event to the DOM changing the `state` variable through the service.

There are two problems in this example:

1. The first close button (with the ng-click property on it) only changes the state on the second click
2. The two buttons without the ng-click are not changing the state at all

*main.html*

```
<div ng-controller="main">
  State: {{ api.isOpen | json }}
  <div ng-click="" open>
    <button>Open - Working fine</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-click="" close>
    <button>Close - Works, but only on second click</button>
  </div>
  <div open>
    <button>Open - Not Working</button>
  </div>
  <div close>
    <button>Close - Not Working</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*main.js*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('main', ['$scope', 'state', function($scope, state) {
  $scope.api = state;

  $scope.api.isOpen = false;

  $scope.$watch('api.isOpen', function() {
    console.log('state has changed');
  });
}]);

myApp.directive('open', ['state', function(state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: '<button>Open</button>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        state.isOpen = true;
      });
    }
  };
}]);


myApp.directive('close', ['state', function(state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: '<button>Close</button>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        state.isOpen = false;
      });
    }
  };
}]);

myApp.service('state', function() {
  return {
    isOpen: null
  };
});
```

Comment: how about you remove your directives open and close and instead use `ng-click="api.isOpen = true"` and `ng-click="api.isOpen = false"`. It is better to use native directives rather than binding a `click` event

Comment: @floribon there is a lot more functionality in my real directives, therefore I can't use ng-click. Besides that, I really want to know why this is not working properly.

Comment: I see. Then remove the `ng-click` and only keep your directive. What was happening is that `ng-click` were triggering a scope digest so it seemed to be kind of working but was unreliable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are using a native event listener on `click`. This event is asynchronous and out of the Angular digest cycle, so you need to manually digest the scope.

```
myApp.directive('open', ['state', function(state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          state.isOpen = true;
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7h95ct1y/

I would suggest changing the state directly in the ng-click: `ng-click="api.isOpen = true"`

Comment: It seems like this is the correct answer! Thanks alot. Here's a working example of my problem using your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/yLeLuard/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should put your link function as a pre-link function, this solves the problem of the second click.

https://jsfiddle.net/2c9pv4xm/

```
myApp.directive('close', ['state', function(state) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    link:{
     pre: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        state.isOpen = false;
        console.log('click', state);
      });
    }
    }
  };
}]);
```

As for the not working part, you're putting your directive on the div, so when you click on the div it works but not on the button. Your open directive should be on the button.

Edit: other commenters suggested that you change the state directly in the ng-click. I wouldn't recommend it, it might work in this case but if you're bound to have more than an assignation to do it's not viable.

Comment: My mistake. I read your code too quickly. Putting the link as pre works, however the presence of ng-click seems to be mandatory for some reason.
Edit: however using scope.$apply is not really recommended, it forces a new digest cycle and if your app contains a lot of watchers it could slow down the digest of the whole page. If you're using just the ng-click i would put it in a function.